# regex to find match in element of list

Tags: python, regex, list, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and have complied a list of items from a file that has the an element which appeared in the file and its frequency in the file like this

```
('95.108.240.252', 9)
```

its mostly IP addresses I'm gathering. I'd like to output the address and frequency like this instead

```
IP               Frequency
95.108.240.252   9
```

I'm trying to do this by regexing the list item and printing that but it returns the following error when I try `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

This is the code I'm using to do all the now:

```
ips = [] # IP address list
for line in f:
    match = re.search("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line) # Get all IPs line by line
    if match:
        ips.append(match.group()) # if found add to list

from collections import defaultdict
freq = defaultdict( int )
for i in ips:
    freq[i] += 1 # get frequency of IPs

print("IP\t\t  Frequency") # Print header

freqsort = sorted(freq.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: item[1]) # sort in descending frequency
for c in range(0,4): # print the 4 most frequent IPs
   # print(freqsort[c])  # This line prints the item like ('95.108.240.252', 9)
    m1 = re.search("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", freqsort[c]) # This is the line returning errors - trying to parse IP on its own from the list
    print(m1.group()) # Then print it
```

Not trying to even parse the frequency yet, just wanted the IPs as a starting point

Comment: `freqsort[c]` is tuple

Comment: Which line is throwing the error BitFlow?  As in which `re.search` is causing problems, or which line in general?

Comment: Does `('95.108.240.252', 9)` appear on a line by itself

Comment: @JonClements it does when I print it, that was copied from the output

Comment: just use re. findall("(ip regex)", line)[0] to capture and accumulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in `re.search()` should be string and you are passing `tuple`. So it is generating an error saying that it expected `string` or `buffer`.

**NOTE:-** Also you need to make sure that there at least 4 elements for IP address, otherwise there will be `index out of bounds` error

Delete the last two lines and use this instead

```
print(freqsort[c][0])
```

If you want to stick to your format you can use the following but it is of no use

```
m1 = re.search(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", freqsort[c][0]) # This is the line returning errors - trying to parse IP on its own from the list
print(m1.group())
```

Comment: The simpler line is much better for what I need thank you. Though I don't understand your note

Comment: @BitFlow you are using `for c in range(0,4):` loop..what happens if there are less than 4 elements(IP addresses)..it will generate `list index out of range` error..

Comment: The 4 is actually a variable N in my code and there are some 70 lines instead though I did notice it return an error when I tried to enter a higher number. Would something like `if N > len(freqsort): sys.exit(2)` work to prevent that? 
Edit: removed `<` replaced `>`

Comment: @BitFlow It will work fine..you can use it..Edit :- or you can keep a counter..and when it exceeds `len(freqsort)` you break the loop..this will print some value until there are no more values present

Answer (score 1):

Use a byte object instead:

```
# notice the `b` before the quotes.
match = re.search(b'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', line)
```

Comment: That returned this error `TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object`

Comment: That's odd. Did you try to print `line`?  What does it output?

Comment: Here's one line, there are over a hundred:`95.108.240.252 - - [14/Feb/2013:00:59:06 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 534 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"` 
which is a line as it appears in the file I'm reading

Answer (score 0):

Try regex with positive  and negative lookaround.

```
(?<=\(\')(.*)(?=\').*(\d+)
```

First captured group will be your IP and second frequency.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you say where that would go, what it would do or how it affects what I already have?

Comment: ah, I just listed regex but will follow an example

Comment: Saleem, I think he's looking to fix the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ipaddress` and `Counter` in the stdlib to assist with this...

```
from collections import Counter
from ipaddress import ip_address

with open('somefile.log') as fin:
    ips = Counter()
    for line in fin:
        ip, rest_of_line = line.partition(' ')[::2]
        try:
            ips[ip_address(ip)] += 1
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(ips.most_common(4))
```

This'll also handle IPv4 and IPv6 style addresses and make sure they're technically correct not just "look" correct. Using a `collections.Counter` also gives you a `.most_common()` method to automatically sort by the most frequent and limit it to *n* amounts.